# is it okay to use GNU public license to create application to a company?

Tags: javascript, open-source, extjs, licensing, gnu

Am i allowed to use Extjs java script library vaersion which published under GNU public license to create a web application for a private company?

Regards

Comment: Have a look at the [GPL FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLInProprietarySystem), it's not so easy to say.

Comment: Ask the client. They're the only one who can say what is acceptable to them. Some might be OK with it, some might not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be up to the company.  Generally speaking, however, JavaScript is one of the few places where you can get away with using GPL'ed code in a corporate context.  All of your JavaScript source code and HTML markup needs to be publicly accessible anyways, so it makes no difference if you're forced to open-source it under the terms of the GPL.  It's already open in the sense that anyone who wants to can view it and save a copy.

Really though, you should consult the company that you are doing the work for.  They may have their own opinions on the issue.